# Infinite loop with method of the typeclass Ord

Tags: haskell

I defined a data type:

```
Data Card = Card Int deriving (Show, Eq)
```

(I defined also a type synonym:

```
Type Cards = [Card]
```

)

and then make it instance of:

```
 instance Ord Card where
    x > y   |ix == iy   = False
            |ix == 0    = True
            |iy == 0    = False
            |otherwise  = (ix > iy)
        where 
            ix = label x
            iy = label y
```

Then when I type:

```
 (Card x) > (Card y) :: x,y are Int
```

it works, but when I type:

```
 [(Card x)] > [(Card y)] :: x,y are Int
```

it goes in loop.

Why does it happen? How do I fix it?

Comment: Please don't use tabs for indentation. They screw up your code's display.

Comment: You know you can derive `Ord` too (just like `Eq` and `Show`), right?

Comment: @Dan In this case, it looks like the autoderived `Ord` would define the wrong order.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your `Ord` instance for `Card` only defines `>`, but [you need to define either `<=` or `compare`](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/base-4.4.1.0/Prelude.html#t%3aOrd):

> Minimal complete definition: either `compare` or `<=`.

The `Ord` instance for lists defines `compare` in terms of the underlying data type's `compare`. By default `compare` and `<=` are defined in terms of each other, hence they don't terminate when called if you have not defined either of them. The other `Ord` operations for list (including `>`) are defined in terms of `compare`, hence why `>` doesn't terminate when you call it on `[Card]`.

Comment: I'd personally recommend defining `compare`. I can't really say why but it just feels right.

Comment: If nothing else, you're less likely to misremember "must define `compare`" as "must define `>=`" or "must define `>`".

Comment: @DanBurton one reason is that if you define '<=', '==' and all missing inequalities can be defined along the lines of a == b = a <= b && b <= a, so 2 applications of <= are used. If you define compare, all (in)equalities can use only one application of compare.